# How do I give stuff to an iron golem?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I keep reading stuff that says I need to give them a poppy, a diamond,  an iron ingot, but I don't know how to actually HAND it to them, like actually GIVE it to them. I just don't know how to give it to them.

Answer (score 3):

You cant, whoever told you that was lying.

Iron golems do sometimes drop poppies when killed and sometimes give them to baby villagers, you might be confused about that. But there is no way to "give them a poppy, a diamond, an iron ingot"